# "author" rel tag works on one author but not another

Tags: google-authorship, rel-author

Here's one page I've managed to get authors set up on properly, no errors:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scirra.com%2Fblog%2F42%2Fwelcome-to-the-new-website&view=

And here is one on another that throws an error with a different author:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scirra.com%2Fblog%2F46%2Fmore-on-html5-audio-codecs-and-politics&view=

> Error: Google Profile does not link to article site

As far as I can tell, they are both identical in the way they are set up! I am really struggling to see the differences here.  Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Ashley's Google profile has a link set up to his profile page and we did check the box saying "This is about me".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull up the two Google profiles in consecutive tabs. Switch to the "About" tab in both. See how yours has that "Other profiles" section at right, with a link back to scirra.com? Ashley's doesn't.

The verification process looks at the Google profile page for a backlink to the claiming site. [See here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1408986), second bullet under "Associate your content with your Google Profile".

Comment: Thanks!  The link was there but wasn't set to viewable by everyone which fixed it :D